Jetpack Compose. Выравнивание по центру экрана
Canvas(Modifier.size(300.dp).background(Color.Transparent)) { 
drawCircle( 
color = Color.DarkGray, 
center = center, 
radius = 80.dp.toPx() 
) }

Рисует круг в левом верхнем углу. Как сделать так чтобы круг был по центру без использования Column и Row?

Ну Box же. Он позволяет такое центрирование.
